# How do I print overlined text using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code (taken from another forum) to convert numbers to Roman numerals. But when it comes to a number like 5000 I need to print overlined V because V is 5. How do I overline characters I need?

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body onload="promptForNumber();">


<script>
    function promptForNumber(text)
{
    if(text == '' ){
     text = "Please enter a number from 1 to 100";   
    }
    var n = parseInt(window.prompt(text, ""));

    toRoman(n);
}

function toRoman(n) {
    var r = '',
        decimals = [9000, 8000, 7000, 6000, 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1],
        roman = ['ix', 'viii', 'vii', 'vi', 'v', 'iv', 'MMM', 'MM', 'M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
    for (var i = 0; i < decimals.length; i++) {
        while (n >= decimals[i]) {
            r += roman[i];
            n -= decimals[i];
        }
    }
     document.write(r);
}

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, changed to iv

Answer (score 1):

Use `\u0305` after each character to overline.

`i\u0305v\u0305` becomes i̅v̅

Comment: thank you very much) Sorry for a lame question, but I must be sure - will this work with every font I'll use?